# how to make a webhook to send a message with the avatar and nickname of the user execute command discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I would like that when I run the `ordinarie` command the avatar and the nickname of the bot change by adding both the avatar and the nickname to get this result

[image]

Edit 1:
I realized that I have to use webhooks for this to happen and I did a couple of searches but never touched webhooks.
How could I do? I leave you the code below to know if I have to work inside or "outside" this command.

Edit 2:
I have tried doing `webhook.send` but I have no idea how I could activate a webhook! advice?

Edit 3:
I finally created a webhook but when I want the bot to add the reactions it gives me `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'.`
I tried to see if I found the id of the message by doing `print (message.id)` but it gives me the same error so the problem is that despite me before using `webhook.send` I use message = it does not count it as I could do with `channel. send` first. How do I resolve?
Below I have updated the code.

code:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["Ordinarie","ORDINARIE","ord","Ord","ORD"])
@commands.has_any_role(690951634183782461, 690954867346243624, 690956686147453048, 690960692051705896)
async def ordinarie(ctx, *, proposta):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    channel = client.get_channel(637761152654508062)
    if ctx.channel.id == channel.id:
        diocane = ctx.author
        favore = get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Favorevole")
        contro = get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Contrario")
        flore = get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Astenuto")
        WEBHOOK_URL = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/765735283831603201/x2i974bNeGwUq13I5p0WmGaviVrkkhsX8IIcQTgnTSr4F9vOFzEi9bK19pD6Bi_6ogos"
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url(WEBHOOK_URL, adapter=discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
            message = await webhook.send(content=f"**Proposta Ordinaria di {diocane.mention}**\n\n{proposta}\n\nVOTA A FAVORE [{favore}]\nVOTA CONTRO [{contro}]\nASTIENITI [{flore}]", username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await message.add_reaction(favore)
        await message.add_reaction(contro)
        await message.add_reaction(flore)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        message = await webhook.fetch_message(message.id)
        await message.remove_reaction(favore, client.user)
        await message.remove_reaction(contro, client.user)
        await message.remove_reaction(flore, client.user)
        thumbsup = get(message.reactions, emoji = favore)
        thumbsdown = get(message.reactions, emoji = contro)
        neutral = get(message.reactions, emoji = flore)
        if thumbsup.count > thumbsdown.count:
            await webhook.send(content=f"**Risultati della proposta di {diocane.mention}**:\n{thumbsup.count - 1} a favore, {thumbsdown.count - 1} contro e {neutral.count - 1} astenuti.\nLa proposta di {diocane.mention} è stata approvata e l'organo incaricato dovrà pertanto applicarla.", username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            WEBHOOK_URL = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/765738529803468820/QyQ_zXzEF_q2EzH1ijTVBZY5L-hxru7lR1EsFoL7L1b5IdbpQe7uiQjVjcBET77C0wjS"
            async with ClientSession() as session:
                webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url(WEBHOOK_URL, adapter=discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
                await webhook.send(content=proposta, username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                return
        if thumbsup.count < thumbsdown.count:
            await webhook.send(content=f"**Risultati della proposta di {diocane.mention}**:\n{thumbsup.count - 1} a favore, {thumbsdown.count - 1} contro e {neutral.count - 1} astenuti.\nLa proposta di {diocane.mention} è stata rifiutata e pertanto non potranno essere presenti in altre proposte i contenuti di questa per i prossimi 30 giorni.", username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            return
        if thumbsup.count == thumbsdown.count:
            await webhook.send(content=f"**Risultati della proposta di {diocane.mention}**:\n{thumbsup.count - 1} a favore, {thumbsdown.count - 1} contro e {neutral.count - 1} astenuti.\nLa proposta di {diocane.mention} è terminata in parità e pertanto spetterà al Triumvirato decidere a riguardo tra le opzioni finite in pareggio.", username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            return
```

Comment: you can only edit nickname, for avatar its not yet possible to do with code, you need to go to discord developer portal to change the bot's avatar

Comment: I found that webhooks are needed to do what I want to do but I don't know anything about their use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example for how to use a [webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#webhook-support) with the name and avatar changed to the invoked user, you should be able to modify it for your needs:

```
WEBHOOK_URL = "<redacted>"

from aiohttp import ClientSession

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, message: str):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = discord.Webhook.from_url(WEBHOOK_URL, adapter=discord.AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))

        await webhook.send(content=message, username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

[image]

Note that webhooks are channel specific, so if you want this to work in more than one channel it's gonna get messy.

For adding reactions, things get more complicated.  A webhook object created by URL does not have all the required data, so we have to pull it from the `Channel` object:

```
# keep track of each webhook per channel perhaps?
WEBHOOK_ID = 748726283772624896

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, message: str):
    webhook = discord.utils.get(await ctx.channel.webhooks(), id=WEBHOOK_ID)

    if not webhook:
        # webhook does not exist, create and store the id possibly?
        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(...)
        # store webhook.id here?

    m = await webhook.send(content=message, username=ctx.author.name, avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url, wait=True) # wait=True will make this return the 'Message' object
    await m.add_reaction('\N{OK HAND SIGN}')
```

[image]

Comment: Part of the problem has been fixed but now I have another one.
When I want it to add reactions ([code here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/695039353868648508/765744488118616074/unknown.png)) it gives me this error ([error here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/695039353868648508/765744888313544744/unknown.png)).
As I understand it being a webhook it needs to be addressed differently but there are no other ways to add reactions other than `message.add_reaction`. How can I do?

Comment: I found a way to use multiple channels but I would like to know something.
Is it possible to have the webhooks directly created by the bot? With this method it is I who create webhooks from the server but if I wanted to have them created directly by the bot, how could I do? [Here is an example image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/765736656866508800/unknown.png). Sorry for the trouble

Comment: I cannot access any of those images

Comment: I try to send full links (it gives me access).
code = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/695039353868648508/765744488118616074/unknown.png
error = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/695039353868648508/765744888313544744/unknown.png
example = https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/765736656866508800/unknown.png

Comment: I get an access denied, I'm guessing because am not in the guild you are sending those in, please put them on imgur

Comment: strange usually did log in. I directly updated the code and entered the error in the question above. (Really sorry for the inconvenience)

Comment: Now I have officially solved. I recommend adding to the response even if the command is run from another channel (like suggest for example). Thank you so much you really helped me! When I can, I'll give you the 50 points!